# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka: How to delay sending a message in a method annotated with @Transactional

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I need the producer to send messages to the topic after the completion of the method annotated as @Transactional, and if an exception is thrown in the method, the message should not be sent to the topic (or rolled back before the consumer reads it).
Is it possible to configure the producer in this way?

`spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:3.1.1`

My application.yml configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          transaction:
            transaction-id-prefix: tx-
            producer:
              configuration:
                enable.idempotence: true
                retries: 1
                acks: all
```

P.S. In this configuration, the offset always commits.

Comment: why cant you call kafka producer in separate method  based you success or failure of the @Transactional method ?

Comment: [Datta Diware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7807754/datta-diware) I can make a call to different methods inside a method annotated as Transactional. One of these calls is a call to the producer, and there may be more logic after it. If an exception is thrown after calling the producer, then the message has already been sent by that time.

Comment: First of all whatever you are asking is not technically possible. Second you mentioned you need to call kafka producer once your @Transactional  annotated method is completed. So either call kafka producer at the end of the method or return something from the method and based on return value call the producer.